# Creating Evenhub topic with EventHubManagementClient

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-eventhub, azure-identity, defaultazurecredential

I'm trying to create an EventHub topic within a namespace through my .net core application. I'm a bit struggling with the authentication and couldn't figure out exactly what should I do to get the Token credentials from Azure.

Should I use ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder? and if yes how exactly I give access to the specific EventHub namespace and get all the data required (clientId, clientSecret, Authorithy and TenantId)?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: microsoft.Identity.client, azure.resourcemanager.eventhub and microsoft.azure.management.eventhub

Comment: The answer will differ greatly between the current management library (Azure.ResourceManager.EventHubs) and the legacy library (which is deprecated and not recommended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the legacy package is deprecated and not recommended, this is based on use of the current generation management package, `Azure.ResourceManager.EventHubs`.

There is no need to work with `Microsoft.Identity.Client` or any of the related types; the auth story for the current generation has been simplified to work directly with `Azure.Identity` token types that manage token acquisition implicitly.

There's a full sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.ResourceManager.EventHubs/samples/Sample1_ManagingEventHubs.md), but the important parts are:

```cs
// Create your client
ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Get the subscription
SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

// Get the resource group
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroupAsync("myRg");

// Get your Event Hubs namespace
EventHubsNamespaceCollection namespaceCollection = resourceGroup.GetEventHubsNamespaces();
EventHubsNamespaceResource eventHubNamespace = await namespaceCollection.GetAsync("myNamespace");

// Create your Event Hub
EventHubResource eventHub = 
    (await eventHubCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
        WaitUntil.Completed, 
        "myEventhub", 
        new EventHubData())
    ).Value;
```

More information on using `Azure.Identity` to authenticate can be found in the [Overview docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet).